# Как создать событие если пользователь вышел в aiogram

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня есть небольшой код, который при выходе пользователя из группы пишет об этом:

```
from aiogram import Bot, types, Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram import md

bot = Bot(token=token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

@dp.message_handler(content_types=[types.ContentType.LEFT_CHAT_MEMBER])
async def left_user(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f'Пользователь <a href="tg://user?id={message.left_chat_member.id}">\
{message.left_chat_member.full_name}</a> вышел из беседы ', parse_mode='html', disable_web_page_preview=True)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Но почему-то он не пишет о выходе, если в чате больше 50 человек, как можно сделать, что бы он писал при любом количестве участников?

Answer (score 0):

```py
@dp.message_handler(content_types=[ContentType.LEFT_CHAT_MEMBER])
async def left_user(message: Message):
    await bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{message.left_chat_member.mention} покинул нас.')
```

У меня так работает, в чате 73 человека